In my asus , my screen is stuck / freeze on windows password screen what do I do?
I just enabled the Ubuntu pro version and applied the settings for nvidia proprietary tested . Then when I started to boot it but then it was stuck in login password screen and can't do anything anymore

using ALT+F2 should give you access to the terminal from there you can get journalctl and see what is going on.
